# Is it JavaScript or Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know this isn't programming-related, but I'm curious what this community thinks about the subject. My understanding is that JavaScript is what the language is named. Lately, it seems to have become trendy to write it Javascript. Who are we to rename the language? I'm interested to hear if there is a cogent argument for changing the capitalization. Thanks for indulging me!

Comment: You're absolutely right: it's not programming-related.

Comment: What is important is how the language is specified and how it is implemented in the relevant browsers (and other types of environments). It is not important how the language is named. The community may even give it stupid nick-names, but that is not relevant. Again, what matters is how the language is specified/implemented.

Comment: @Andrew, Just google for javascript and go to the wikipedia link. The answer is in the title of the article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Answer (score 35):

It's [`JavaScript`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Answer (score 20):

The official name is [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript), though it really doesn't matter in practice :)

[You can view the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript).  Note that JavaScript is not the same as ECMAScript as the other answers suggest, it's an *implementation of* ECMAScript.

Comment: Agreed, JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript, but the problem arises when you say for example: *"I'm a JavaScript developer"*, you are not trying to say that you develop *only* for that implementation... The term *Javascript* has been used as a "generic" way to call the language without making any reference to the *Mozilla implementation*.

Comment: @CMS: I actually stumbled upon the Wikipedia article for this concept accidentally earlier today: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pars_pro_toto

Answer (score 10):

It's spelled ECMAScript.

Comment: This is incorrect, JavaScript is not ECMAScript, it's an **implementation of** ECMAScript, there's a big difference there.

Comment: Pedantry always gets in the way of the bad jokes. Point ceded.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt), the programming language is called JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is trademarked by Sun, which is now Oracle. The true naming is ECMAScript but JavaScript is the well known name for it.

Comment: The letter case is not important for trademarks in US law, therefore JavaScript, Javascript, or even JaVaScRipT is a trademark by Oracle, see: http://tess2.uspto.gov/

Comment: Correct, I should have said "The word JavaScript (case insensitive) is..." instead of just "JavaScript is...", my preferred way of typing it, to prevent confusion. Thanks for the clarification so that no one is confused.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for ECMAScript!

Sounds like CW, by the way.